# Is this proof of the surjectivity of the left inverse function $g$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the surjectivity of $g: Y \to X$ in $g \circ f =id_X$ (with $f: X \to Y$) and would appreciate any corrections.

$$$$
Definition of surjectivity:$$\forall x \in X \exists y \in Y: g(y)=x$$

$$((g(y)=x \land g(y) \in g(Y)) \implies x \in g(Y)$$ 
$$\implies X \subset g(Y)$$
$$(X \subset g(Y) \land X \supset g(Y)) \Leftrightarrow (X = g(Y))$$

How can I also specify that the implication in the 2nd to last line is a result of the all quantifier in the defeinition of surjecitivity? Thanks a lot!

Comment: No. It is not correct. You are trying to *prove* $\forall x \in X \exists y \in Y: g(y)=x$. Instead, you started by assuming that was true and - I'm not entirely sure here, but it looks like you decided to prove that the definition you implies the other common definition of $X = g(Y)$ (which it does - the two definitions are equivalent). What you know here is that there is an $f$ such that $g \circ f =id_X$. You need to start with that, and prove your definition of surjectivity from that fact.

Comment: What I was trying to do is work from the definition of surjectivity to arrive at the equivalent formulation $X = g(Y)$, thus proving that g is indeed surjective. Furthermore, do you mean the identity has to be used in the proof? If so, does this prove that $g$ is surjective?
$y=f(x)$
$$g(y)=g(f(x))=id_X(x)=x$$
Thanks

Comment: Proving one definition of surjectivity from another definition of surjectivity *that you simply assumed applied to $g$* does not prove that $g$ is surjective. If you want to prove $g$ is surjective, you have to prove it from information you actually know about $g$, which in this case is that there is a function $f$ with $g \circ f = id_X$. You start with that information, which you are given, and from it prove *either one* of those two equivalent definitions. Your outline above is correct, but needs to be spelled out properly. "For $x \in X$, set $y = f(x)$. Then ..."

Comment: Alright thanks a bunch